# How can I load markers from MySQL database dynamically?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, google-maps

I have a MySQL database where I stored some marker position (along with some other information) which I loaded into google map. I followed the example -

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax.html

and it worked fine for me.

Now what I want to do is, suppose a user will be able to choose an id of a specific marker and clicking on a button it will be loaded onto the map. Not sure how to load the specific marker on the map dynamically.

Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have set up an example [here](http://tallymobile.com/test5.html). I am using the Google Geocoding API to receive co-ordinates of the address entered by the user and creating the marker using Google API V3 as shown below
**Ajax Request to get the co-ordinates**

```
$.getJSON("getjson.php?address="+address,
  function(data){
   lat=data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
   lng=data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
   point= new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
   map.setCenter(point);
   zoom = 14;
   marker = createMarker(point,"<h3>Marker"+(markersArray.length+1)+" "+point+"</h3>",zoom);
});
```

**PHP Code to return the co-ordinates**

```
<?php

$address = $_GET['address'];
$address=str_replace(" ","+",$address);
if ($address) {
 $json = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address.
 '&sensor=true');
 echo $json;
}

?>
```

**Creating the Marker**

```
function createMarker(latlng, html,zoom) {
   var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latlng,
  map: map,
  zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
 });

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
 });
 marker.MyZoom = zoom; 
 return marker; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all i see in your link that you use v2.Try to use v3 at least now that you are at the beginning since the v2 is deprecated.

As of your question i can only tell you the procedure and then you can make it happen.

---

**1. User interaction**
    User interacts with UI and selects i.e. a range of prices(0-100).

**2. Ajax request**
The client sends an ajax request to server to get json with [jquery getJson()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) or any other way.

**3. Server Respond**
  A php page responds to your ajax call and make a query in mysql getting a resultset of position-markers,[converts it in json](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php) and send it back.

**4. Parse respond**
[Parse the json](http://www.json.org/js.html) back to the client and create markers.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found this one great help
http://www.svennerberg.com/2012/03/adding-multiple-markers-to-google-maps-from-json/

Create a json object as given the link and pass it to javascript .

function createMarker(json){

```
for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
    var data = json[i],
    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);        
    // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    title: data.title
    });
}
```

}